# ¿Cómo invoco una funcion de python desde la terminal en Linux?

Tags: python

soy nuevo en python y tengo esta duda. En el IDLE de Python de Windows cuando ejecuto un script de python con distintas funciones me permite invocar la que yo quiera, sin embargo cuando lo ejecuto en la terminal de Linux (utilizo Manjaro), simplemente finaliza el proceso sin dejarme llamar la funcion deseada.

Por ejemplo, en el siguiente código:

```
def test():
    print("Hola mundo");


def suma():
    a=int(input("Escribe un numero");
    b=int(input("Escribe otro numero");
    c=(a+b);
    print("La suma de tus numeros es: ", c);
```

En la términal del IDLE de python en Windows me dejaría llamar sin problemas a "test()" por ejemplo, pero no puedo hacer lo mismo en la terminal de Manjaro o el la de mi editor (uso atom), el programa sólo finaliza.
¿Existe alguna forma de poder invocar la función deseada?

Comment: Tienes que llamar a python pasando el parámetro -c: $ python -c 'import foo; print foo.hello()' puedes ver más detalles en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987041/run-function-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 1):

`idle` es un entorno integrado de desarrollo (**IDE**) y adopta un modelo conocido como **REPL** (read–eval–print loop), es decir, leer el input del usuario, evaluarlo, imprimir resultados, y comenzar de nuevo. La ejecución que haces cuando escribes en la terminal `python script.py` tiene un modelo de trabajo distinto, se lee el script, se lo evalúa completamente, se imprime cualquier salida y se finaliza la ejecución. Podríamos decir que falta el "loop" del modelo REPL con el que trabaja `idle`.

En cuanto a tu ejemplo:

```
def test():
    print("Hola mundo");

def suma():
    a=int(input("Escribe un numero");
    b=int(input("Escribe otro numero");
    c=(a+b);
    print("La suma de tus numeros es: ", c);
```

Vemos que son solo dos funciones, pero no existe en el código ninguna llamada a estas, por consiguiente, ninguna se ejecutará al hacer `python script.py`. Deberías agregar al final, la invocación a alguna de ellas, por ejemplo:

```
suma()
```

o mucho mejor:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    suma()
```

Esta última forma es la manera para poder hacer que un script pueda ser "importable" por algún otro y al mismo tiempo "ejecutable" desde la terminal. De cualquiera de las dos formas, al hacer `python script.py` se ejecutará inmediatamente la función `suma()`.

Por otro lado, si quieres trabajar en la terminal, con un modelo similar al de `idle`, puedes invocar `python` sin parámetros, lo que te ofrece un entorno REPL similar (no idéntico) al de `idle` pero en la terminal. Tendrás un símbolo donde eventualmente podrías importar tu script:

```
>>> from script import *
>>> suma()
```